# Where does Chrome keep the SQLite Database file it writes things like stored passwords to?

Tags: google-chrome, sqlite

Just like the title says, where does Chrome keep the SQLite file that holds things like stored passwords. I've found the follow database files and neither one of them hold the stored password information -

`C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases\Databases.db`

and

`C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Sync Data\SyncData.sqlite3`

Comment: The passwords are encrypted George. What did you find there?

Comment: I am aware, doesn't change the fact that they're still stored in a SQLite Database though, and I need to find the file to that database. And all I found on those two were metadata, models, and shareinfo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong places. By the way, the passwords are encrypted.

Use SQL-Lite viewer to view the contents of the file **Login Data**.

In Windows: `LocalAppData\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data`

In Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Login Data`

Comment: +1 but How do I open this file? Its not an .sqlite3 file

Comment: Dont worry, just get a SQL-Lite viewer, and open it. I just tried it.

Comment: So what you are saying is that chrome synch encrypts and stores your passwords locally but usernames are plainly visible?

Comment: I answered this 2 years ago, can't remember more :-)

Comment: No there are not, there are freeware tools to decrypt.

Comment: Show us Max how to decrypt then

Comment: Max wanted to say there is tools to extract the passwords while the same OS with the same user and pass is running; see nirsoft  chromepass https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html  , but if the login data file is moved to a new OS then you cannot extract the passwords unless you brute force attack it

Answer (score -2):

Once you find those files you can use Chrome password decryptor to see the password database if I remember corectly.

Comment: this should be comment.